# When an image is uploaded to the Media Library, how long does that image stay on the Recently Updated Images list before it falls off the list?

Tags: media-library

I think the answer is “it stays recent until the media cache is clear”.  However, I am not 100% sure that is the best answer.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of which dialog you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my findings, this shows you the images from the system on the basis of some criteria. It doesn't mean that it will get removed if you clear the cache.

So to clarify it more, when you try to add an `image` in the `image field`, you can choose the image based on some criteria given on the left side of the `Select Media` dialogue like below.

[image]

Now if you go to the `core` database, you will get to know from where these criteria are defined. So go to the `core` database and on this location

```
/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/SelectMediaDialog/PageSettings/SearchConfigs
```

you will get all the `SearchConfigs` that it is using to filter out the results. And on each config you will get some criteria.

Like for the "**Recently Uploaded Images**", you will see that it has a field checked called "**CreatedWithin7Days**" that shows you the images those were created with in 7 days.

[image]

If you uncheck this, you will see the filter will not work and you will get all the images when you click on the **Recently Uploaded Images** option.

So for each of the criteria on the left, there is a `SearchConfig` define in the `core database` and if you want to extend the functionality of any of these configs then you need to extend the pipeline that is holding this functionality.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to write this.  The post is very helpful.

Comment: @ChristopherW Kindly accept the answer if you think it resolves your query. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use "Recently uploaded images" option, there is a query sent to Solr:

```
?q=(((_path:(3d6658d8a0bf4e75b3e2d050fabcf4e1) AND _language:(en)) AND __smallcreateddate_tdt:[2022-10-07T07:31:54Z TO 2022-10-15T07:31:54Z]) AND (_template:(f1828a2c7e5d4bbd98ca320474871548) OR _template:(daf085e8602e43a68299038ff171349f) OR _template:(c97ba92380094858bdd5d8be5fccecf7) OR _template:(eb3fb96cd56b4ac997f8f07b24bb9bf7))) AND _val_:__boost&start=0&rows=20&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_master_index)&wt=xml
```

Notice the part

```
__smallcreateddate_tdt:[2022-10-07T07:31:54Z TO 2022-10-15T07:31:54Z])
```

While in theory, as per Sumit answer, it should take last 7 days, in fact it returns images where `__Created` is within last 8 days from now.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to write this.  The post is very helpful.